# Rotating the X and Y axes of a Chart

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to rotated my 3D Column chart. So far I have the following:

```
ActiveChart.Name = "44 Chart 7"

With ActiveChart
    .SetSourceData Source:=pzx.Range("L126:M135")
    .HasTitle = False
    .HasTitle = True
    .Shapes("44 Chart 7").ThreeD.RotationX = 0
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Classification Actions"
    .ChartArea.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 140)
    .ChartTitle.Font.Name = "Arial"
    .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 10
    .Legend.Font.Size = 8
    .Legend.Font.Name = "Arial"
    .ChartStyle = 11
    .ChartArea.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
   End With
```

I have two questions -

1) what determines how a chart is named if you do not actively name the chart yourself
2) do you know why this code does not work

Here is the error I received -

Run-time error 7
Out of Memory

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming objects have **naming conventios** that you must follow. For charts: when a chart is on a worksheet the `Name` property applies to the `ChartObject` object which is the **container** for the Chart.

```
With Chart
   .Parent.Name = "myChartName"
End With
```

or

```
`Sheets(1).ChartObjects(3).Name = "Name of my Chart"`
```

or

```
`Sheets(1).Charts("My old Chart Name").Name = "Name of my Chart"`
```

If you know where your chart is residing, point to chart with sheet reference to be in the safe side than using `ActiveChart`. If you do not actively name the chart, then you must use chart's default original name to refer to it. Or its index.

Please try this code piece in your end.

```
Option Explicit

Sub createMyCharts
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim mychtObject As ChartObject
Dim myChart As Chart

'-- put anything else you need to delcare and set

Set mySheet = Worksheets(1) '-- set according to your sheet

'-- delete any old leftovers to clean up
For Each mychtObject In mySheet.ChartObjects
  mychtObject.Delete
Next

'-- create new chart
Set myChart = mySheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=30, Width:=500, Top:=30, Height:=200).Chart

With myChart
  .ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xl3DColumn '-- the full chart Type
  .SetSourceData(mySheet.Range("L126", "M135"), Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns)
  .Rotation = 30
End With

'-- do anything else you need to do
```

End Sub

Reference to [MSDN Chart Rotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.chart.rotation%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

After trying out, you may comment and happy to help futher if you have any questions. :)

Comment: I also used .Elevation, .Perspective, as well as .Rotation. Thanks!